# How to access an UIImageView from cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an imageView in custom cell of a tableView. I am accessing that imageView in `cellforRowAtIndexPath` by using `viewWithTag`. But how can I access that imageView in another functions? Like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: You shouldn't want to. Use the data model. And if you have a custom cell you shouldn't be using tag, use a property.

Comment: @Wain what do you mean exactly by using the data model?

Comment: You have a set of data which tells you how to configure the cell, that is your data model and the true source of data. The cell should not be queried to get that info.

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking he needs to get the ImageView to set the image, not read it.

Comment: Fair enough, that's a suitable use case to want to get the image view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` to access the cell, then from the cell you can access it's subview(contents) using `viewWithTag` as-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
     // access the cell for selected cell
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     // from cell using viewWithTag:image view's tag access imageView 
     UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:CELL_IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the cell for the given indexPath

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And then just access the imageView

```
cell.imageView
```